# Scrollbars in scrollable div's in mobile browsers cross-platform

Tags: javascript, android, css, webkit, scrollbars

I'm using scrollable div's (with the CSS element overflow:scroll) to build me a page for tablets running Android 3.2+, BlackBerry Playbook and iOS5+ (iPad 1 not supported).
I got this working but I would like scrollbars. For iOS5 there is this supported webkit code snipped which I add to the CSS styles. This makes really nice 'native' like apple scrollbars:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Is there something similar which works on Android and the BlackBerry? A CSS/webkit solution would be best but JavaScript is fine too as long as it's not a large plugin as iScroll or similar.
What I tested too but doesn't work as it 'lags' really bad on all platforms is the following:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just looked at another post and found [jScrollbar](http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jScrollbar/). This is an option I'll try, but is there something more rudimental like the one for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet found a cross platform CSS solution for this yet. I have how ever used a lightweight js solution touch scroll https://github.com/neave/touch-scroll

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This scrolling method has a nice 'momentum' but it still doesn't provide scrollbars. This is only half a solution for the trouble I have :S